# How to display as a column, if row id is referenced in another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Having two tables:

```
[TableRule]
|RuleId (PK)|
|RuleDesc|
...

[TableRulesByUser]
|UserId|
...
|RuleId (FK)|
```

I want to retrieve all `TableRules` with an extra column that display if this RuleId is used(referenced).

I tried something like:

```
select v.*,
            case
                when
                    (select count(b.RuleId) from TableRulesByUser b
                    join v on b.RuleId = v.RuleId  ) > 1
                    /* Here the join doesn't work */
                then 'Y' IsUsed
                else 'N' IsUsed
            end
    from TableRule v
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
select 
v.*,
case when b.RuleId > 1
then 'y' 
else 'n' 
end
from tablerulesbyuser b
join tablerule v
on b.ruleid = v.ruleid
Group BY RuleDesc
```

Comment: doens't work give me the following error `ORA-00905: missing keyword` in `then 'y' isused`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
V.*,
CASE WHEN U.RuleID IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
FROM TABLERULES V
LEFT JOIN TABLERULESBYUSER U ON V.RuleID = U.RuleID
```

Not sure if the syntax is correct for PLSQL, but the idea is to LEFT JOIN the other table and you'll get null if it isn't used, then display N, else Y.